# Too many Custodian badges

Tags: discussion, review, review-badges

I just got awarded the third "Custodian" badge on StackOverflow. Given my current reputation (< 800) I have access to two review queues only. So where did the third badge come from?

When taking a deeper look into my badge history, I got awarded one Custodian badge for reviewing late answers and one for reviewing first posts. The third badge I got was for reviewing an edit made to one of my answers.

Is this the purpose of the Custodian badge - or should it just be awarded for reviews of changes made to *other people's* posts for >2k users?

Comment: Well, you still reviewed someone *elses* edit. Even if its on your post.  I think you should still get the badge :P

Comment: What @Lix said. From the moment you posted your question or answer, it's not really _your_ post anymore, it now belongs to the community. Reviewing an edit to it is not essentially different than reviewing an edit to any other post.

Comment: I agree with @YannisRizos that the post I made belongs to the community and that reviewing that edit is nothing different that reviewing other posts.
The question I raised however was whether such edits should count towards the Custodian badge or not. Because I didn't decide "Lets go and review some posts to do some good to the community" rather the system _requested_ that I review this edit.

Comment: I was under the assumption that only things actually done in the review panel were counted towards the total. However, since I got the Steward badge for suggested edits, they've definitely backfilled data for all the suggested edit stats, which wouldn't have been discriminate of the review panel or not. I'm not sure if new ones only count from the panel itself or across the entire site.

Comment: @animuson Suggested edits is the only review data that was backfilled in the new review system (the others will not be, as the rules changed, even if slightly).

Comment: @animuson this is a specific question about the Custodian badge why change to other badge? OP is not talking about the Reviewer badge.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Generally, we can stick to a single badge that covers all the badges of the same class. What makes a Custodian badge any different from a Reviewer badge other than the 1 and 250 actions completed?

Comment: @animuson I was under the impression that [meta-tag:reviewer-badge] is only for the specific Reviewer badge - and it's not like we don't have several tags for specific badges already. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Expanding on [Lix's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148129/too-many-custodian-badges#comment425435_148129):

1. **It's not your post anymore**

   From the moment you posted your question or answer, it's not *your* post anymore, it now belongs to the community. You do retain some privileges as the original author, for example you can approve the edit by yourself and don't have to wait for another user to approve the edit. If you decide it's good, it's good, if not, well, that's that.
2. **Still counts as reviewing**

   The system might have informed you that there's a pending edit on one of your posts, and you might not at all be interesting in reviewing other people's posts, however you did review the edit and you did decide whether it should be approved or not. That, in my book, still counts as reviewing, as the end result is the same: Either an improved post, or a bad edit was rejected.

Badges, especially bronze ones like Custodian, are just small & silly incentives. You're overthinking this.

Comment: That's inconsistent, though, with how the other badges work. For example, on one site I helped close 2300 questions and made 3600 edits, but I don't have Steward or even Reviewer for either of those activities, because I did these things directly, without taking a detour via the Review queues.

Comment: @ЯegDwight No disagreement there, and not to mention that mod actions don't count as review actions (even if you do them through the `/review` mod link), we deal with most of the crap and no badge :( Not to mention that we are ineligible for Marshal once we get our diamond... I've done 1.5K+ edits and closed 2.4K+ questions on Programmers, still I have to go through stinkin' `/review` to get the badges. Oh well.

Comment: "You're overthinking this" - you're probably right about that... ;)

Comment: @YannisRizos Your badge is your diamond ;) Diamonds are worth WAY MORE than bronze.